# Submitting material to PhilPapers without a university affiliation

Tags: paper-submission, preprint

I am not currently affiliated with a university.
Can I submit a paper to PhilPapers?

When I started to create an account with a personal email address, I got this message:

> The email address that you entered is not from a recognized university or college domain. If you continue, your submissions to Phil* services will be subject to review and limitations. For this reason, we strongly recommend using an academic email when possible.

What does it mean that submissions "will be subject to review and limitations"?

Comment: https://philpapers.org/help/faq.html#sources have at look at the FAQs, you will find info there, see: "Why do you want to know my affiliations and background?"

Comment: @Sursula-they- Would you please clarify? I had read that before posting my question. It explains certain limitations on visibility of submissions and posting to forums. However, it does not explain limitations on the submission process or what is meant by "review", so it does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: "it helps to determine posting privileges in the forums (posting is unlimited forphilosophy faculty/PhDs and graduate students and restricted for others)" so this clearly refers to the limitations - if you are not affiliated with a university, you will have limitations in forum postings

Comment: @Sursula-they- I understand but that is not my question. I am asking about submitting a paper, not posting in a forum.

Comment: What are you trying to submit? A bibliographic reference to a paper already published? A paper? What?

Comment: @Buffy I guess preprint is the best word for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a guess, but it accords with a few other sites. The requirement is most likely a "sanity" check to try to weed out cranks before they get into the system. I'd guess that philosophy, being a broad field, draws more than the normal share of cranks.

Try to find someone, such as an editor, that you can ask about the limitations. They may want some assurance that you aren't a crank, such as a recommendation from an academic.

But the limitation could also be on how often or how much you submit. And a review is natural for most publishers, though less so for preprint publishers.

Most journals are happy to post things from non-academics, so I assume the you won't be closed out entirely. But you may have to work your way in to the community slowly.

It is important that they do allow you to continue and don't immediately slam the door.

It does, however, seem that PhilPapers is primarily an index and bibliography of material published elsewhere, rather than directly submitted work. They describe themselves as a service to academics.  While it also does preprints, you might think about submitting to one of the journals they index.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reaching out to them over email, and then social media like Facebook/Linkedin (if they don't reply within reasonable time).

The thing is, they would know more about their policies and how to explain it to users.

Comment: You email them if you want the bounty.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I just gave some input based on what I have heard about a similar platform, Arxiv. I marked question as community wiki so that people can freely add/edit (believe this will hamper the "bounty", as was prompted on the screen before I submitted)

Comment: Thanks, my comment was tongue-in-cheek.